# Looping through multiple excel files, Finding a string, and returning the values in adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 400 excel files (technical reports) each one with different 5 tabs with different names. I need to create a master spreadsheet with certain information of each one of these reports (information always on the same tab)

I have a code (copied from here) that can be used to find the information in a specific cell.

The problem is that the reports' structure is not consistent, the good news is that on the adjacent cell to the information I am after, there is always the same text "Water Level:".

I am after a macro that can search for this text string, copy the adjacent cell, and return it to this master spreadsheet.

Please see the code I mentioned:

```
  Sub Test()
' Adjust the path below as required
MyPath = "C:\Users\bcf00637\Desktop\pilelogs\V2\"    ' Set the path.
myname = Dir(MyPath, vbNormal)    ' Retrieve the first entry.
Do While myname <> ""    ' Start the loop.
    ' Ignore the current directory and the encompassing directory.
    If myname <> "." And myname <> ".." Then
        If (GetAttr(MyPath & myname) And vbNormal) = vbNormal Then
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & MyPath & "[" & myname & "]Approval Form'!R1C1" ' change the part after the ] to your sheets name
           ' also change the R1C1 on the end to pick up the cell you want ie R2C3 for cell C2
           ' do NOT change the 1st one (.FormulaR1C1) this is part of the command.
           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = myname
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
    myname = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A few queries in comments as the details of your question are unclear.

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Range, wb As Workbook

mypath = "C:\Users\bcf00637\Desktop\pilelogs\V2\"
myname = Dir(mypath, vbNormal)

Do While myname <> ""
    If myname <> "." And myname <> ".." Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mypath & myname)
        If (GetAttr(mypath & myname) And vbNormal) = vbNormal Then
            'have left this line as not sure what it does
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & mypath & "[" & myname & "]Approval Form'!R1C1"
            'change sheet name to suit
            Set r = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").usedrange.Find(what:="Water level:", lookat:=xlWhole,matchcase:=false)
            If Not r Is Nothing Then
                'puts cell to the right in column A of master sheet
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End.xlUp(2).Value = r.Offset(1).Value
            End If
        End If
        wb.Close False
    End If
    myname = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick, thanks for answering, it doesn't really work, but thanks!

Comment: Ha, do you want to tell me how it doesn't work so I can make it work?

Comment: Well, I copied the code, deleted the line "activecell.formulaR1C1..." changed the path and the sheet; ran the macro and.. nothing happened.

Comment: You need to check my comments and step through the code to see what's going on. Probably the text is not found or perhaps it's copying the wrong cell.

Comment: SJR, the code is now showing an error on this line :  Set r = wb.Sheets("Casing Record").Find(what:="Water level:", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) "the object does not admit method"??   I might be a bit out of my depth...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify a range to search. I have added `usedrange` in that line but if you know "Water level" will only be found in a particular range you can narrow it down to make the code more efficient.